# Tag manager and Pardot forms

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, pardot

We are trying to track the users acquisition data for a goal before the form submission is submitted and taken off the site. I once had it working back in july where a general page view trigger would happen BEFORE the event of the form submission was fired. This used to bring us the data inside of the acquisition overview in analytics letting us know social, paid etc. Right around july 20th, the function had stopped working all together and the data all (and still is) coming through as direct. Nothing really had been changed that was directly connected to the BEFORE fire.

Ive found other guides on tracking pardot and such but there was nothing that was able to send the data before it left getting the information before its sent off.

Does anyone have any idea why something like this would stop working if nothing on the pardot side or the triggers had changed? Or has anyone been able to achieve what im trying to do without the mess of chaining triggers?

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the exact code that stopped working. That's sort of detail is expected on this site.

Comment: Code? The only code being used to connect these programs is the global tag manager code. Should I include screenshots of how my triggers and tags are setup?